# Creating C structs in Cython

Tags: python, c, struct, cython

I'd like to create my very own list container using Cython. I'm a very new begginer to it, and following the documentation I could get to creating such a structure :

```
cdef struct s_intList:
    int    value
    void*  next
ctypedef s_intList intList
```

but when comes the time to acces the struct members, I can't find the good syntax:

```
cpdef void  foo():
    cdef intList*    li
    # li.value OR li->value
```

throws : "warning: intlists.pyx:8:12: local variable 'li' referenced before assignment"
which let me assume that my cython structs usage is incorrect...

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong here please? :)
Thank you for you help

Comment: I get `Cannot convert 'void' to Python object`, but if I fix that there's no error. You either have an old Cython version, or you're not showing the relevant part of your code.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to allocate the memory for the intList. Either with a local variable or 
using malloc.

```
cdef struct s_intList:
    int    value
    void*  next

ctypedef s_intList intList

cpdef object foo():
    cdef intList li
    li.value = 10
```

Comment: Nice! Seems I was missing the 'object' return type. Any documentation about this anywhere? :-)
Thank you very much!

Comment: Alternatively, leave out 'object'. At least in Cython 0.16, it should return `None`.

Answer (score 6):

In your code, `li` is a *pointer* to an `intList`.  This pointer is not initialized to point to anything, so accessing `li.value` is meaningless (and erroneous).

In fabrizioM's answer, an `intList` is created (not a pointer to one) on the stack, so there is a location in memory reserved for `li.value`.

If you want to create an `intList` with actual data (which I gather you intend to be like a linked list data structure), and if you want to be able to return that `intList` from functions, etc.  you will have to allocate your `intList` structs on the heap and build up the full linked list from there.  Cython allows you to call `malloc` (and `free`) easily to do this.